# Hook script to move SVN files from local to remote

Tags: svn

Just wondering if someone could help me with the following issue.

On my local Windows 2003 Server I have VisualSVN installed. Now what I want to do is move these files on a commit from the local server to my hosted (dedicated) Linux web server.

I have no idea about how to approach this and have never written a hook script; therefore some help is doing this would be grately appreciated.

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you may find of help. The same thing can be accomplished with any type of language - even batch script on Windows.

http://imrannazar.com/Automated-Deployment-with-Subversion

Comment: Hi, do you have a .bat example that I could review please?